# Changing ASP.NET MVC 3 folder structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am interested in changing the structure folder. I have read many articles, but I have not found the solution.

I want to do so to distribute the files and folders on thematic folders. I have created a base class BaseViewEngine from RazorViewEngine

```
public class BaseViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
    {
        public BaseViewEngine()
        {
            MasterLocationFormats = new[]
                                    {
                                        "~/Themes/My/master.cshtml"
                                    };

            ViewLocationFormats = new[]
                                    {
                                        "~/Modules/{1}/{0}.cshtml"
                                    };


            PartialViewLocationFormats = new[]
                                    {
                                        "~/Blocks/{0}.cshtml"
                                    };
        }
    }
```

But it is not working.

### Update

Control is primitive. Only for test

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var test = new Test { Text = "Hello" };
            return View(test);
        }

    }
```

And View

```
@model DemoModules.Test


<h2>Index</h2>
```

But when I run project. I Get error

> CS0103: The name of the 'model' does
>   not exist in the current context

About structure folder, see the source of subject matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the web.config file in the default Views folder. There's some stuff in there that is required for Razor views to work - particularly the base class for views and the namespaces that will be used to compile the view.

Answer (score 8):

You don't really have to implement a new engine to change the paths, you can just register them as you want:

```
private static void RegisterViewEngines(ICollection<IViewEngine> engines)
{
    engines.Clear();

    engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine
    {
        MasterLocationFormats = new[] { "~/Themes/My/master.cshtml" },
        ViewLocationFormats = new[] { "~/Modules/{1}/{0}.cshtml" },
        PartialViewLocationFormats = new[] { "~/Blocks/{0}.cshtml" },
    });
}

protected void Application_Start()
{
    RegisterViewEngines(ViewEngines.Engines);
}
```

---

For reference, the default paths are as follows (not including Areas):

```
ViewLocationFormats = new [] {
  "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
  "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
  "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
  "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
};

MasterLocationFormats = new [] {
  "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
  "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
  "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
  "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
};

PartialViewLocationFormats = new [] {
  "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
  "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
  "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
  "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but not helped. Control not see View, and View not see Control

Comment: @Greg, show your controller and your folder structure so I can have an idea

Comment: I just want to add that while this works for simple customization of the view location, developers need to be careful to account for all the required permutations of the newly specified location, because this will override and wipeout any location formats that are provided by the default view engine.  Investigate the source code (a disassembler such as .Net Reflector works well) to see the default implementation

Comment: Used dotPeek to get the default settings concerned, and added them to the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Check out this post: http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/06/27/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location.aspx

Hope this helps.